# Apache Spark with Python newbie

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am new to programming in general and now am studying ApacheSpark with Python
i got an error which i cannot figure out what was i doing wrong.
my code as below :

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector

numpyVector = np.array([-3, -4, 5])
print '\nnumpyVector:\n{0}'.format(numpyVector)

# Create a DenseVector consisting of the values [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
myDenseVector = DenseVector([3.0,4.0,5.0])
# Calculate the dot product between the two vectors.
denseDotProduct = myDenseVector.dot(numpyVector)
```

error message :

```
File "<ipython-input-140-d5af743190a3>", line 4
'incorrect value for myDenseVector')
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you're in python2?

Comment: did i post in the wrong place ? i am also very new to stackoverflow as well , sorry

Comment: No, it's just that you're using python2 syntax, and that type of error sometimes happens if you try to run python2 code with python3

Answer (score 0):

For lab 1 3c, what you are trying to do is creating a (myDenseVector) based on the values of the (numpyVector). This is the wrong assumption do not do this. The exercise asks to create DenseVectors indipendent of the numpyVector, once you create this, then proceed to create a the dot product of  numpyVector and your (myDenseVector).  This will give you the correct result